# Open triangle arrow in TikZcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'm trying to make a diagram in `tikz-cd` with an arrow of the `open triangle` form (in `stmaryrd` it would be `\rightarrowtriangle`).

If I write something like `A\arrow[rightarrowtriangle]{r}{e} &B`
I get an error. How can I change the arrow type in `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide us with a minimal compilable example showing what you've got so far to help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try `\arrow[r,-{Triangle[open]}`. Here `Triangle[open]` is an arrow tip from the `arrows.meta` library, which `tikz-cd` loads for you. (See documentation in the manual for `pgf`/TikZ, section 16.5.) Note this uses the usual TikZ syntax of a hyphen (`-`) followed by an arrow tip. The curly braces are required due the the brackets giving the `open` option to `Triangle`.

If you want to set the default arrow tip for all diagrams, or for a specific diagram, use the technique described in section 2.2 of the `tikz-cd` manual, shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r,-{Triangle[open]}] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[ % set default options for this diagram
  arrow style=tikz, % use tips from arrows.meta
  >={Triangle[open]} % set default arrow tip
]
A \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}

% use \tikzcdset to define setting for all following tikzcd-diagrams
\tikzcdset{
  arrow style=tikz,
  >={Triangle[open]}
}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```